# "TypeError: window.require is not a function" in Electron/Angular sample app

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, typeerror

So I’m very new to Angular and Electron, and I've been having difficulties getting things to work. I've been looking for sample apps so that I could have a starting point that I could understand, and I came across this: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/20/build-desktop-app-with-angular-electron

I've been following it, and at the point where I first run `npm run electron` the window opens but stays empty, and in the devtools console I find `Uncaught TypeError: window.require is not a function`.

I had made just some minor adjustments (making some types explicit) because initially it wouldn't compile, but nothing that should change anything about this.

I have done some searches and for what I understand it might have something to do with

```
const electron = (<any>window).require('electron');
```

not being in `electron/main.ts`, but I genuinely don't know what I'm supposed to do. I tried adding `webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true}` in the `BrowserWindow` constructor, but to no avail.

I'm at a loss; I don't understand the framework enough to resolve it myself.

Edit: npm v6.14.8, node v10.19.0, electron v12.0.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can take a look over [this](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) repo from GitHub. you'll be able to understand the whole concept between angular and electron boostraping.

Comment: That's what worked best for me. I'm still trying to understand how to do stuff without breaking everything but it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you use this code instead of the other code, it might work:

```
const electron = require("electron");
```

If this does not solve your problem, I would switch to vanila js

Comment: Unfortunately, this line gives an error and doesn't even compile: `Error: src/app/images.service.ts:4:18 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'.`